# Equivalent of MySQLs TO_DAYS function in R

Tags: r, date

In MySQL there is the TO_DAYS function to convert a date to an integer

For example

```
SELECT TO_DAYS('2016-12-22')
```

gives `736685`

Is there an equivalent of this function in R?

Comment: Yes, this is a dupe. You can do it with lubridate or as.POSIXct

Comment: No it is not as his _offset_ or _origin_ is unusual.  For today, R itself has 17157 which is orders of magnitude different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `as.Date()` which can take an integer or numeric argument.  You will need to supply a proper origin.  Just guest-imating this seems to work:

```
R> as.Date(736685, origin="0000-01-01")
[1] "2016-12-22"
R>
```

If you want to generate the same number that MySQL produces, you again need to account for its offset:

```
R> as.numeric(as.Date("2016-12-22"))
[1] 17157
R> as.numeric(as.Date("2016-12-22")) + 
+                  (as.Date("1970-01-01") - as.Date("0000-01-01"))
Time difference of 736685 days
R> as.numeric(as.Date("2016-12-22")) + 
+                  as.numeric((as.Date("1970-01-01") - as.Date("0000-01-01")))
[1] 736685
R>
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want

```
as.Date('2016-12-22') - as.Date('0000-01-01') # 1st day of year 0
# Time difference of 736685 days
```

or

```
to.days <- function(date.string) difftime(as.Date(date.string), as.Date('0000-01-01'),
                                          units='days')

to.days('2016-12-22')
# Time difference of 736685 days
```

Comment: Correct, but twice the same answer.  You also get a difftime object from the first  -- as you can tell from the output.  Just wrap it in `as.integer()` or `as.numeric()` to get just the number.